# I need to know whether device is in geofencing or not in backend of NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, expo, geofencing

I am creating NodeJS backend for uber like app for android and iOS.  locations of users will be taken from phone and coordinates i.e. latitude and longitude will be sent to server. There are 2 groups of users. lets say drivers and passengers. once passenger press search for driver, I need to send notifications to all the drivers with in 5 km of the passenger radius. Any ideas how to implement this logic .??.
On frontend geo fences will be created around the passengers. what I cant figure out is that how to know on the server side if drivers are in those geo fences or not.
Frontend is also being developed by me using react native so any suggestions from frontend point of view are also welcome. Thanks

Comment: Which database you're using on backend? MongoDb or MySQL?

Comment: @BYIRINGIROEmmanuel i am using MongoDb. native version not the mongoose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB support Geospatial queries, with that you can query document in the specified geolocation bounds.

Assume that we have `drivers`  collection as below

```js
db.drivers.insertMany( [
   {
      name:"Patrick Konrab",
      location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.97, 40.77 ] },
   
   },
   {
      name: "James Webb",
      location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.9928, 40.7193 ] },
      category: "Parks"
   },
   {
      name: "Kyle Grill",
      location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.9375, 40.8303 ] },
   }
] )
```

The following operation creates a `2dsphere` index on the location field:
`db.drivers.createIndex( { location: "2dsphere" } )`

The `drivers` collection above has a `2dsphere` index. The following query uses the `$near` operator to return documents that are at least `1000 meters` from and at most `5000 meters` from the specified GeoJSON point, sorted in order from nearest to farthest:

```
// Passenger coordinates should be returned user device
//https://github.com/react-native-geolocation/react-native-geolocation

const passengerCoordinate = [ -73.9667, 40.78 ]

db.drivers.find(
   {
     location:
       { $near:
          {
            $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: passengerCoordinate },
            $minDistance: 1000,
            $maxDistance: 5000
          }
       }
   }
)
```

Comment: Thanks. After your comment i googled and found these docs that worked for me. Cheers Sir. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/